# Service Worker Config - Network then Cache

Tags: html, caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am working on a HTML5 PWA and am looking to have a "Network First, then Cache" layout so that when a user accesses the PWA it pulls down the latest version but if they are offline it uses cache.

How would i need to amend the below code for that please?

```
const assets = [
  "/",
  "/index.html",
  "/about.html",
  "/assets/css/main.css",
  "/images/logo.png",
  "/images/logo.svg",
]

self.addEventListener("install", installEvent => {
  installEvent.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then(cache => {
      cache.addAll(assets)
    })
  )
})

self.addEventListener("fetch", fetchEvent => {
  fetchEvent.respondWith(
    caches.match(fetchEvent.request).then(res => {
      return res || fetch(fetchEvent.request)
    })
  )
})
```

The cache is created, but once the PWA is saved to homepage it always uses Cache.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the ["network, then cache" pattern](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#network-falling-back-to-cache) from the [Offline Cookbook](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/):

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(async function() {
    try {
      return await fetch(event.request);
    } catch (err) {
      return caches.match(event.request);
    }
  }());
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, really appreciate that. I am new to Service Workers, so would that just be appended to the bottom of the sw.js?

Comment: That code would replace the `fetch` handler you have right now.

Comment: Thank you, that's sorted my problem in the web platform. What I am finding now though is that when accessed from my "Added to Homescreen" PWA, offline the pages do not appear to be cached.
The idea of this change was so that the PWA could refresh its Cache and/or provide the latest version when online or failback to cache if no network available.